# Time Series forecasting using caret package in R

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, r-caret

I am trying to forecast using caret package on economic data. Is there any method to predict values for next coming years?

```
library(mlbench)
library(caret)
library(pROC)
library(caTools)
library(ROCR)

myTimeControl <- trainControl(  method = "timeslice",  initialWindow = 36,
  horizon = 12,  fixedWindow = FALSE,  allowParallel = TRUE,  classProbs = TRUE,
  summaryFunction = twoClassSummary,  verboseIter = TRUE) 

modelRF <- train(
  as.factor(class) ~ . ,  data =  TestData,   method = "rf",  metric =  "ROC",
  ntree  = 1000,   preProc = c("center", "scale"),  trControl = myTimeControl)
```

Please help me to predict the class for next coming years.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to use the `predict` method with the `x` data for what you want to predict.

Answer (score 0):

For forecasting time series, first consider that your time series is a regression problem then you can use extreme gradient boosting method which is a time taking model but its accuracy is very good. I have applied many model for time series forecasting like ARIMA, PROPHET, HOLT WINTER'S, EXPONENTIAL SMOOTHING, etc but my forecasting accuracy is best in extreme boosting method although it's a regression model.

```
 train(QTY~BILLDATE1,
       data = train1,
       method = "xgbDART",
       preProc = c("center", "scale"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Tree based models tend to be weak predictors of time indexed economic data. They have some success in panel data. You will be better using support vector machines or LSTM's for time indexed economic forecasts.